# Turtle - What precisely is the turtle's speed? X actions/second?

Tags: turtle-graphics, code.org

A student asked me this and I can't find the answer. You can set the turtle's speed to 0-10. But what does that actually mean? x actions / second?

We are on Code.org, which translates its code in the lessons into Javascript, but this command is found in the Play lab, which provides no translation. I am assuming this is analogous to JS-turtle, but if you know the answer for Python Turtle, etc, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

> What precisely is the turtle's speed? X actions/second? ... if you
> know the answer for Python Turtle, etc, I'd love to hear it.

In standard Python, the turtle's `speed()` method *indirectly* controls the speed of the turtle by dividing up the turtle's motion into smaller or larger steps, where each step has a defined delay.

By default, if we don't mess with `setworldcoordinates()`, or change the default screen update delay using `delay()`, or `tracer()`, then the motion of a turtle is broken up into a number of individual steps determined by:

```
 steps = int(distance / (3 * 1.1**speed * speed))
```

At the default speed (3 or 'slow'), a 100px line would be drawn in 8 steps.  At the slowest speed (1 or 'slowest'), 30 steps.  At a fast speed (10 or 'fast'), 1 step.  (Oddly, the default speed isn't the 'normal' (6) speed!)  Each step incurs a screen update delay of 10ms by default.

Using a speed of 0 ('fastest'), or turning off `tracer()`, avoids this process altogether and just draws lines in one step.

There's a similar logic for how the `speed()` setting affects the number of steps the turtle takes to rotate when you do `right()` or `left()`.

Comment: That is so cool! Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.speed

From the docs you can see that it is just an arbitrary value.